# How to notify of scroll in iframe

Tags: accessibility, browser

For the sake of screen readers such as JAWS, etc.

Given a list of navigation options which are a collection of documents and locations within them, when one is selected the iframe will load and/or 'scroll' to the selected document and/or location.

A sighted person can see the effects of their selection, but how might one effectively provided the means to a screen reader to notify the user of the effects of their selection?

If the best that can be done is some explanation prior to list of options (and perhaps a reference to the iframe as being the recipient of the change,) what means might effectively provide means for the user to jump reading to the navigated location?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot/wireframe to describe the scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a copy of JAWS and/or NVDA?

Thee are some good resources which describe how to use iframes from an accessibility point of view:

http://webaim.org/techniques/frames/

http://lab.dotjay.co.uk/tests/screen-readers/iframes/

http://accessibility.psu.edu/frames/

These links also describe some of the challenges you may face.

Scrolling is not an issue because the screen reader is typically reading from the html and DOM. In JAWS there are additional features (which can be invoked via keystrokes) which allow the user to list and cycle through frames on a page, so it is important to name your frames using the title attribute.